# How do I map a simple object into a complex object that contains a list with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am reading in a JSON file

```
"data": [
    {
      "workPhaseID": 1,
      "workPhaseName": "Phase 1",
      "millID": 1,
      "millName": "Mill 1",
    },
    {
      "workPhaseID": 2,
      "workPhaseName": "Phase 2",
      "millID": 1,
      "millName": "Mill 1",
    },
    ... ergo there is a list of mills and each mill contains a set of work phases
]
```

that gets converted into a list of simple objects. I want to convert the simple object list into a list of complex objects so that the main object is the mill and the mill will contain a list of work phases related to it. Then I can push it out as a new JSON.

I can find a lot of examples on how to flatten a complex object into a simple one using automapper and I can find a few examples of simple -> complex mappings here in stackoverflow but none of them match my case exactly and I can't piece the info together enough to get my specific case done, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the classes:

```cs
public class WorkPhaseDO
{
    public short WorkPhaseID { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhaseName { get; set; }
    public byte? MillID { get; set; }
    public string MillName { get; set; }
}

public class MillDO
{
    public string MillName { get; set; }
    public byte? MillID { get; set; }
    public List<WorkPhaseForMillDO> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class WorkPhaseForMillDO
{
    public short WorkPhaseID { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Ergo I want to map WorkPhaseDO into MillDO

I know that if I did not have a list and instead the last line in MillDO was "public WorkPhaseForMillDO Lines { get; set; }" then this map would work:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<WorkPhaseDO, MillDO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Lines, act => act.MapFrom(src => new WorkPhaseForMillDO()
    {
        WorkPhaseID = src.WorkPhaseID,
        WorkPhaseName = src.WorkPhaseName,
    }));
});
```

However this is not enough, I need to have a list of work phases under each mill object.

Thus the end result should be a list of MillDO objects (1 object = 1 mill) and each MillDO should contain a list of WorkPhaseForMillDO objects. The workPhaseID in WorkPhaseForMillDO is an unique number, the workPhaseName is not necessarily unique.

In case it helps understand the object structure I want, the resulting JSON should look like this:

```
[{
    "millId": 1,
    "millName": "Mill 1",
    "workPhases": [{
        "workPhaseId": 1,
        "workPhaseName": "Phase 1"
        }, {
        "workPhaseId": 2,
        "workPhaseName": "Phase 2"
        },
    ...
    }],
    "millId": 2,
    "millName": "Mill 2",
    "workPhases": [{
        "workPhaseId": 5,
        "workPhaseName": "Phase 1"
        }, {
        "workPhaseId": 6,
        "workPhaseName": "Phase 6"
        },
    ...
    }]
    ...
}]
```

Comment: You'll need to use linq to make your groups and then AM to map.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However could you elaborate it a bit? I am a tad familiar with linq, but not enough to fully understand what you mean.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results